# Fetch current url and display on my own HTML page

Tags: python, django

I redirected to a page whose URL is **example/def/5/**. This is the current page URL, and I want to display this URL on the same page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can get current path using [request.path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path):

```
{{ request.path }}
```